# How to use $match after $lookup and $unwind so that it can check all the fields including the array for a keyword/string?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search

I have  collections named
**products**
`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "1"
  },
  "companyId": [
    {
      "$oid": "2"
    }
  ],
  "Title": "abcd",
  "Caption": "abc",

},{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "2"
  },
  "companyId": [
    {
      "$oid": "3"
    }
  ],
  "Title": "milk",
  "Caption": "aa",

}

`
```

**companies**

`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "2"
  },
  "name": "cathub",
  "url": "cathub.com",
  "__v": 0
},

  "_id": {
    "$oid": "3"
  },
  "name": "Amule",
  "url": "amule.com",
  "__v": 0
```

`
here the **products** collection have *companyId* as foreign key of *_id* from **companies** collection.What i need is that when i search for a perticular string in **products**,it needed to search all fields including **companies** which is joined.for example if my keyword is "Amule",then it needed to search in title and caption and companies.name also.if it found matching then we need to return the **products** document of _id:2

**I tried with the following**

`{ $lookup:{ form:"companies", localField:"companyId", foriegnField:"_id", as :"result" } }`

then

`{ $unwind:{ path:"$result" } }`

but i am not able to perform $match after that.Because it shows error and only allow to use $match
only in the begining.Please help to solve this issue(i need to solve this issue using TEXT index)

**Complete query**

```
 model.aggregate([
                 {
                   $match: {
                     $text: {
                       $search: "Amul",
                     },
                   },
                 },
                 {
                   $lookup: {
                     from: "companies",
                     localField: "companyId",
                     foreignField: "_id",
                     as: "company",
                   },
                 },
                 {
                   $unwind: "$company",
                 },
    
                 {
                   $match: {
                         $text:{
                              $search: "Amul"}
                   },
                 },
                },


               $group: {
                 _id: {
                   _id: "$_id",
                   Title: "$Title",
                 },
                 comapany: {
                   $push: "$company",
                 },
               },
]}
```

if the **string** **'Amul**'present in any field of **"products"** then **return the documen**t or '**Amul'** is present in the **"name"** field of joined **"company"** joined using $lookup then also return the **parent document**

**note:-**
*'model' is the products collection*

Comment: Please show us your entire code. Usually it should work, you can place `$match` at any stage.

Comment: added the complete query.i am using $text and $search inside $match

Comment: error showing : $match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline stage